# iOS 8 WKWebView: display local plain text like iOS 9?

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm attempting to view a local log file using a `WKWebView`, due it's higher performance and asynchronous loading vs. `UITextView`. On iOS 9, the `loadFileURL(_:allowingReadAccessToURL:)` works perfectly to load the plain text file and display it. It even renders with a monospaced font (I wish I could set it to Menlo though). However, on iOS 8, local file URLs can't be loaded but I can load the text file as a `String` and use `loadHTMLString(_:baseURL:)` to load it into the view. This works, but the text is rendered, as expected, as if it was HTML. That means there are no line breaks or appropriate wrapping for long lines. It also renders with the default font, which is not monospaced.

I'm guessing I could attempt to load some JavaScript that loads some styling, but I have no experience with that and I'm hesitant to put that much effort into what's essentially debug log viewer.

So my question is, how can I render plain text as plain text, from a local file, using `WKWebView` on iOS 8?

Comment: Have you tried putting <pre> tags around it? Still work but a lot simpler than JS injection.

Comment: @pvg That actually worked, though I'm a bit scared of the performance implications of `let renderString = "<pre>\(logString ?? "No log yet.")</pre>"`. It also doesn't seem to obey the minimum font size I set in the `WKPreferences`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the performance aspect of this, what is so performance critical in a debug log viewer? How can rendering it in a browser possibly be faster than rendering it in a text component? etc.

Comment: @pvg Loading a large text file into a `UITextView` is very slow and synchronous, making the app essentially freeze when trying to view the logs. It was also buggy when trying to implement a scroll-to-bottom behavior. I've been able to use `WKWebView` for asynchronous rendering and scrolling to the bottom works, once I found a way to tell when the content had actually been rendered (observe the web view's scroll view's contentSize property `setContentOffset` when it changes).